# Where are my Roles being stored?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, roles, roleprovider, data-storage

I've enabled `Roles` in my ASP.NET web application, but I'm slightly confused as to where they are being stored. In my old project, each Role would appear in the ASP.NET Roles table, and I could see them. However, in my new project, I can't see any Roles in the database table. The strange thing is, I can still use them (and the default Roles/Membership API) and everything works fine. Any ideas why they are not appearing the database table itself, and where they are actually being stored?

My `web.config` file has this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

Using the ASP.NET configuration tool, my default Role provider is `AspNetSqlRoleProvider`.

Thanks
**Update**
I added this explicitly in my web.confg

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" >

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="myDBConnectionString" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: @Skoder can you show your web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it does use the local database unless the role provider points to a database using a different database connection.

If you setup the tables in your own custom database and not the ASPNETDB.mdf file, then you will have to setup a custom provider definition pointing to the SQLroleprovider, and provide a custom connection string reference to where the database is.

HTH.

Comment: Ah, that's sorted it. I added provider details in the roleManager section. Strange it didn't appear automatically as in my previous project, I hadn't explicitly added anything, yet it was the default.
Oh well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your asp.net membership database are two tables: aspnet_Roles contains the roles and aspnet_UsersInRoles contains the association of users with roles.

Comment: That's what I expected, but there's nothing in there.

Comment: Do you executed the aspnet_reqsql utility and selected the roles tables for generation?

Answer (score 0):

it will build it’s OWN database in the App_Data folder and create the required tables there

Comment: There's nothing in my App_Data folder. I've updated my tags to show I'm using SQL Server 2005 (forgot to put that in)

Comment: run this aspnet_regsql untility you will find it created a database called aspnetdb

Comment: Hi, I already have the asp membership tables. The users I create appear in the tables and I can access them. I can also access the roles, but they're not showing in the tables.

Comment: u said you already have the membership tables and then u said they're not showing in the tables , can't get it  ?